# How do I add a custom event handler to FileZilla Server?

Tags: c#, ftp, filezilla

I'd like to add an event handler to the FileZilla server.  It would be fired whenever an upload completes.

Serv-U has this feature and I'm hoping that FileZilla does as well.  I have a requirement to move off of Serv-U due to licensing requirements.

I would prefer a C# solution, but anything that works would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else finding this post.

There is not a built-in feature to add event handlers.

The source code of the server is available, is written in unmanaged C++ and compiles with Visual Studio.

There are functions related to logging that could be leveraged to add event handling, but some of the required data (filename and user information for example) is stored in protected or private variables.  This makes it difficult to access both the name of the file, user etc at the point in the code where files are determined to be successfully moved, or if they've failed.

At this time, I'm not sure that it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. This can be used to create a C# event on file upload for any ftp server.